# How to share rows between two tables on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to do something like this:

[image]

As you can see they must be in the same html page and should transfer rows without refreshing the entire page again.

Someone can give me some help?

Comment: Nice illustration, now where's your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does this have to do with ajax? This could easily be achievable in Angular, using binding properties.

Comment: *This question is Too Broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a screen shot of the results:

[image]

Here's the important parts of the HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Table 1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in table1">
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"></td>
          <td><span ng-bind="item.data"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="transferRight()">Transfer ></button>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="transferLeft()">< Transfer</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Table 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in table2">
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"></td>
          <td><span ng-bind="item.data"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Here's the important parts of the javascript/angularjs:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.table1 = [
    {checked:false, data:'Data 1'},
    {checked:true, data:'Data 3'},
    {checked:true, data:'Data 4'},
    {checked:false, data:'Data 6'},
    {checked:false, data:'Data 7'}];
  $scope.table2 = [
    {checked:false, data:'Data 2'},
    {checked:false, data:'Data 5'}];
  $scope.transferRight = function() {
    angular.forEach($filter('filter')($scope.table1, {checked: true}), function(value) {
      value.checked = false;
      $scope.table2.unshift(value);
      $scope.table1.splice($scope.table1.indexOf(value), 1);
    });
  };
  $scope.transferLeft = function() {
    angular.forEach($filter('filter')($scope.table2, {checked: true}), function(value) {
      value.checked = false;
      $scope.table1.unshift(value);
      $scope.table2.splice($scope.table2.indexOf(value), 1);
    });
  };
});
```

Here's a link to a working Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/qoARS4mtp5CQQnf1kogA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/picklist.shtml) code. It's completely made with Javascript and html.
It's called a picklist btw.

Answer (score -1):

just use append() or appendTo()

```
$(".toRight").click(function () {
     $("#table1 input:checked").closest("tr").appendTo("#table2"); 
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Rudnitskyi/mydk87cx/2/) full code

Comment: It's tagged under angular, not jquery